# Removing the levels attribute in the output - R

Tags: r, matrix, levels

I am new to R Programming. I wrote a sample program and that returns a value of a particular column in a matrix. When I print the value i get something like this

```
[1] APPLE
2 Levels : 1 2
```

How do I get only the value without the levels in the output.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11):

Just to expand on A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1's comment, the following command is what prints the variable `APPLE` without all that levels stuff:

```
 as.character(APPLE)
```

To get help on the command within R type:

`?as.character`

Here is an online R help entry for the command:

https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/character.html

Answer (score 8):

You can print a factor without displaying the levels by using the `max.levels` argument in `print()`.

Normal printing:

```
factor(letters[1:5])
# [1] a b c d e
# Levels: a b c d e
```

Levels removed:

```
print(factor(letters[1:5]), max.levels = 0)
# [1] a b c d e
```